# The exact solution of the "Get Phone Number in Android"

Tags: android

I try to get my own phone number with this code

```
TelephonyManager Mgr=(TelephonyManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But it  doesn't work regularly.

What is the exact solution of the "Get Phone Number in Android" ?

Thank's

Comment: not all operators include the phone number on the sim card

Comment: I concur with the above comment. It isn't always possible to get your own phone number.

Comment: if any errors shown in the log cat

Comment: Code is return blank string. This way not useful for every operator like moujib's and David's said.

Comment: Before using any code try to check if you there is any phone number on the sim card , on your droid phone go to Settings , then about then phone state and scroll to phone number . if it's blank don't bother coding .

Comment: in the phone state, my phone number is unknown alredy problem is here this code fetch from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the exact solution of the "Get Phone Number in Android" ?

Have the user enter one in an `EditText`, perhaps configured with `android:inputType="phone"`. There is nothing in the Android SDK that supports retrieving the device's phone number, as the device may not know its phone number -- only the carrier needs that. Moreover, there are several scenarios in which the user would need to indicate which of the possible phone numbers they wish to use:

- dual-SIM phones
- people with other phone numbers ported to this device, or using call-forwarding to route calls to this devices
- people with SIP numbers or other VOIP phone numbers they prefer to use with the device

Comment: great answer , once and for all.

Comment: firstly thank's your answers. I wanted to send sms automaticly but apparently its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Send an mms from the phone programmatically to an email address, on your server, and read the from number.

Comment: It's a way but this method costs money to final user so I'm not sure whether it's the best way or not

Answer (score 1):

> TelephonyManager
>    is not the right Solution,Because in some cases the number is not stored in the SIM, Due to my suggestion,You should use Shared Preference to store user's Phone number first time the application is open, and after that the number will used whenever you need in application.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String myNO()
{
    return ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number();
}
```

try this

Comment: This doesn't work all the time. Some operators don't include the phone number on the SIM card and in that case you can't get the number this way.

Comment: thanks for interest but return blank string. this codes interoperability  change according to mobile operator

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
   private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}

private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber(){
    String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
    return s.substring(2);
}
```

Comment: What is your exact need, you wand the Mobile (Device) id or the users mobile number?

Comment: As I commented in other places, this isn't reliable. It only works if the SIM card contains the phone number. In a lot of cases, it doesn't.

Comment: thanks for help Aerrow. your code is true but dont work with every operator(like mine)