# TelephonyManager give me null

Tags: android

Telephone Manager give me `Null` phone number while i have use this code -

```
TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
Log.i(TAG, "PH No"+mPhoneNumber);
```

**Permission::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

it get me `null` when i have print it....

```
06-13 12:29:02.749: INFO/Login(5273): PH Nonull
```

Please help me out this

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443524/getline1number-return-null-but-not-always
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619872/the-exact-solution-of-the-get-phone-number-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755379/how-to-get-my-phonenumber
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278801/how-to-get-the-telephone-number-in-real-device This question has been asked and answered/discussed numerous times. There is no reliable way to get the user's phone number. Period. End of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getLine1Number(); returns whatever is stored on the SIM card's MSISDN, which isn't filled by some operators.

In your case i am pretty much sure The MSISDN is unfilled.

You should keep one thing in mind.

getLine1Number() sometimes return with null value or with the phone number originally stored in SIM card.

Comment: maybe stupid question but do u have sim card in your phone? and make sure it has network